# Восстановить удаленные записи (soft delete) при клике на кнопку Laravel

Tags: laravel

При клике на кнопку восстановления переходит на страницу как пример post/2/restore и пишет not found
web.php

```php
Route::post('/post/{post}/restore', 'PostController@restore');
```

view

```php
@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid back">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <a href="/post/{{$post->id}}">  <img src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}" class="w-100"> </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <p>{{$post->title}}</p>
                        <p>{{$post->created_at}}</p>
                        <p>{{$post->deleted_at}}</p>
                        <form action="/post/{{$post->id}}/restore" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            <button type="button" type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Восстановить</button>
                            <a href="" class='btn btn-danger'>Удалить навсегда</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

PostController.php

```php
    public function restore(Post $post)
    {
        $post = Post::withTrashed()->find(post)->restore();
        return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }
```

Comment: Можно прикрепить скрин ошибки из вкладки network?

Answer (score 0):

Есть догадка, что из-за того, что вы в методе restore(Post $post) пробуете найти $post прежде чем заходите в метод - ларавел не находит нужный пост, он ведь удален, хоть и мягко
Попробуйте int:

```
public function restore(int $post)
    {
        $post = Post::withTrashed()->find(post)->restore();
        return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }
```